# Issues with Ionic 5 keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard

I am currently working on an Ionic 5 and I am facing 2 issues with the keyboard.
When I click on the ion-input and the keyboard appears:

1. The `ion-content` is pushed up so it is right above the keyboard, which **cause everything to be crammed**. I tried a bunch of solutions, but none of them properly worked, and most of them involve `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`, which leaves the `ion-content` as it is, hence the `ion-input` is not visible and so the user can't see what they're typing and they also can't see the next button, so they must first close the keyboard in order to see what they wrote and be able to move on to the next step.
2. When the keyboard is about to dismiss, **it leaves a white space in the space it was taking up**. It's only for a split second but it is visible and makes the app feel like it's slow or lagging.

These 2 issues seem to be very common as I found questions about them since 2014, and I tried most solutions mentioned in the answers but nothing seems to work.

I seem to be having this issue **in this app only**, but I know that it is not an ionic 5 issue as people faced the same issue in older versions.

What the structure of the page looks like, I had to close all code blocks so that I could take one screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

android:windowSoftInputMode is ised for native fields (EditText,etc..) so when you click on native xml it will take effect. All what you need to do is in your androidManefist.xml on line applicarion or activity, there is keyboardresize="adjustResize" which is the default, change it to adjustPan and content will not be pushed up , instead keyboard will go up as actionsheet from bottom without effecting the content.

Comment: Hello Mostafa, So I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" as you suggested but content is still being pushed up.

Comment: @alaaelghazaly can you add in your question a screen shot of the exact thing that is happening when keyboard is opened?

Comment: In another app I just finished a couple of days ago, I found the android:windowSoftInputMode set to "adjustResize". For example, on the login page in that app, when i click on the `ion-input` the keyboard slides up without pushing the page content. Given that, what is the difference between adjustResize and adjustPan?

Comment: Here is what the screen looks like right now: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/gUR8Lyn.png)

Comment: adjust resize is the normal behaivior that native android app behaves, it roll is to push the view up and focus on a field that is focused(clicked) by resizing the page content to fit the resized page ( when page pused up on keyboard show, the view was 100% then it became like 60% for page and 40% for keyboard) so by that it centers the 60% vertically by itself ) while on adjustPan page keeps 100% and keyboard keeps 40% but now keyboard will not push the page up but it will go above the page like a modal behaivior or actionsheet. Thats all the difference.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but it seems that both adjustResize and adjustPan do not have a different effect in this particular app. I have tried both but there seems to be something wrong.

Comment: If you have made css and html fixed at bottom or gave attribute bottom:0 then in both will not differ since the element will be strict to obey its rule to keep viewing on bottom and thus keyboard will go up and thus you element will keep showing, in this case nothing will change, your css should be edited to be correct.

Comment: Indeed the footer section is fixed with bottom:0. If i recall correctly, my teammate used them to fix something related to the image at the top of the page. I will try editing the css and giving the adjustPan another try. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you edit it then keep adjustResize as default since it is the default behavior and for sure its better than adjustPan...

Comment: makes sense, will do. There just seems to be a problem with the footer, it doesn't stay at the bottom, so I am still trying to fix that without using fixed and bottom.

Comment: Remove footer, footer is the problem, footer and ion-tabs could make such problems with keyboard, so try to make it bottom:0 and maybe position absolute without position fixed.

Comment: I will let the team know that we need to use another component other than footer. maybe an `ion-col` of size="12" would simply look just the same.